# How to get Blender to stop recognizing my keyboard in Pop! OS Linux?

Tags: hardware

I just upgraded Pop! OS to 20.04 a week ago. Everything has been good except for Blender :(
Now just seconds after I open any blender file the keyboard stops. I can continue using the mouse but not the keyboard. I have unplugged and replugged the kbd, restarted the computer, to no avail. I have also changed the keyboard to a different one. There’s nothing wrong with the keyboard, its lights do show, and I can use it if I go to another program.
In Windows this won’t happen.

Any ideas?

Thanks guys

Comment: Could it be that you've enabled the BlenderKit add-on? Try to start Blender from the terminal with the `--factory-startup` flag which will load the factory settings (don't open the preferences or they will be overwritten when auto-save is enabled).

Comment: You might be right about BlenderKit! I did have it on! (I will try that later). So far I uninstalled it. It was installed with Snap. Now I installed it with Flatpak, directly from the Pop Store actually. I did not install BK again. I have not used it long enough to know if that did it. But so far so good. I am using it now, I will continue and if I no longer have that problem, I will install BK to troubleshoot. If the problem comes back then I'll start up Blender like you recommended.

Comment: This issue was reported in [T73507](https://developer.blender.org/T73507) should've been fixed in [rBA4fe390b6bad2807f604656752f122861fd26efc1](https://developer.blender.org/rBA4fe390b6bad2807f604656752f122861fd26efc1). The experimental daily builds of 2.83 and 2.90 include the fix.

Comment: Update - Ok, so after 2 hours of use, the issue did not come back! It used to need just 10 seconds to act up. Hence so far, I can say that reinstalling it with a different wrapper (Flatpak) did it. I will update later when I troubleshoot BlenderKit

Comment: Thank you Robert G. I will get 2.83